# Create file in Xamarin Cross Platform App Development

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm new to Xamarin. I'm trying to create a file using code

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
string filename = Path.Combine(path, "myfile.txt");

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
{
    streamWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow);
}

using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(filename))
{
    string content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(content);
}
```

The above code sample is giving me exception 
**System.UnauthorizedAccessException**: 'Access to the path 'C:\Users\hchittora\Documents\myfile.txt' is denied.'

Here is the full stacktrace

```
    System.UnauthorizedAccessException
    HResult=0x80070005
    Message=Access to the path 'C:\Users\hchittora\Documents\myfile.txt' is denied.
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace
   at System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)
   at System.IO.FileStream.CreateFileOpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append)
   at FileHandlingSampleApplication.MainPage..ctor() in C:\Users\hchittora\Desktop\FileHandlingSampleApplication\FileHandlingSampleApplication\FileHandlingSampleApplication\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 19
   at FileHandlingSampleApplication.App..ctor() in C:\Users\hchittora\Desktop\FileHandlingSampleApplication\FileHandlingSampleApplication\FileHandlingSampleApplication\App.xaml.cs:line 16
   at FileHandlingSampleApplication.UWP.MainPage..ctor() in C:\Users\hchittora\Desktop\FileHandlingSampleApplication\FileHandlingSampleApplication\FileHandlingSampleApplication.UWP\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 24
   at FileHandlingSampleApplication.UWP.FileHandlingSampleApplication_UWP_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.Activate_4_MainPage() in C:\Users\hchittora\Desktop\FileHandlingSampleApplication\FileHandlingSampleApplication\FileHandlingSampleApplication.UWP\obj\x86\Debug\XamlTypeInfo.g.cs:line 255
   at FileHandlingSampleApplication.UWP.FileHandlingSampleApplication_UWP_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance() in C:\Users\hchittora\Desktop\FileHandlingSampleApplication\FileHandlingSampleApplication\FileHandlingSampleApplication.UWP\obj\x86\Debug\XamlTypeInfo.g.cs:line 476
```

When I looked at the above issue, I come to know that UWP cannot directly interact with the system files. What can be another alternative to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Xamarin.Forms runs on multiple platforms, each with its own file system, there is no single approach for loading and saving files created by the user.

I can not provide code for all platform here because you need to understand the fundamental for it.  Check [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/files/#Loading_and_Saving_Files) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [SecureStorage](https://github.com/sameerkapps/SecureStorage) library with dependency injection to save on each platform. Although this is mostly used for token caching, you might find it useful.

Comment: I'm unable to run the application on my local machine. It's throwing an error:
The project "Plugin.SecureStorage.UWP" cannot be started directly.

In order to debug this project, you must consume it from a Windows Store app project that creates a package and is marked as the Startup Project.